# How to Render a react component inside a dangerouslySetInnerHTML content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

HTML content getting from server and rendering on UI using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` inside a particular element.

My question is to render React component inside the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` content using some identifiers like `id`.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please show some code, sandbox, what does it mean "inside dangerouslySetInnerHTML"? Rendering as its child or reference it as a string?

Comment: There isn't even a question or a questionmark in this post

Answer (score 0):

While possible, this is sort of the wrong approach. `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` expects a string, so you would have to render the React component to a string and insert it into the HTML string before setting it... or use a hook to manipulate the DOM after it's been rendered, but that's against React best practices; you should let React manage the DOM and its changes.

Since you mentioned getting HTML back from the server, I would suggest making a change there. Instead of returning HTML from the server, return JSON data. On the client side, you can take the JSON and populate the React components you need to render, without using `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` at all.

Returning HTML in response to AJAX calls was common in the early days of AJAX, but it is now standard practice to return "raw" data for exactly these reasons. If some of your HTML is defined client side, and some server side, it will be very challenging to manage DOM scripting & interactivity on the client.

Comment: Yes, agree, but that content has some complexity like contains a math string.

Answer (score 0):

dangerouslySetInnerHtml cannot render react components, because it does not accepts components. It accepts only a html string.